# Azure Automation Runbook - Returning incorrect resource group name. 'Resource group '{resource-group-name}' could not be found'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

We use the following code in a runbook and it is returning an incorrect value for the Resource Group Name.

```
$AzureVMs = Get-AzVM "SH-COMPANY-AD-0"

$AzureVMs | ForEach-Object {
    $AzureVM =  $_
    $job += Invoke-AzVmRunCommand `
    -ResourceGroupName $AzureVM.ResourceGroupName `
    -VMName $AzureVM.Name `
    -CommandId "RunPowerShellScript" `
    -ScriptPath "$env:TEMP\CleanerScript.ps1"
}
```

After investigating the error message we get the following error:
`Get-AzVM : Resource group 'SH-COMPANY-AD-0' could not be found. ErrorCode: ResourceGroupNotFound ErrorMessage: Resource group 'SH-COMPANY-AD-0' could not be found. ErrorTarget: StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: Not Found OperationID : cea02a85-8524-4552-a243-a362c69f6d98 At line:16 char:13 + $AzureVMs = Get-AzVM "SH-COMPANY-AD-0" + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzVM], ComputeCloudException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMCommand`

This should be returning the value of "COMPANY-INTERNAL-CLOUD" as that is the resource group it is housed in.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Name` in your command like so: `$AzureVMs = Get-AzVM -Name "SH-COMPANY-AD-0"`

When using Get-AzVM without specifying the argument, it will assume you are asking for all Virtual Machines in the `SH-COMPANY-AD-0` resource group. It is good practice to always specify your PowerShell arguments.

See [Get-AzVM in MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-11.1.0) for more details.